# Undefined index: id Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

My Tables:

> **kategoris table**
>
> id | kode_kategori | kategori_name |
>
> **items table**
>
> id | kategori_id | item_name

In items table the `kategori_id` column has foreignkey.

**My Controller:**

```
 public function edit($id)
  {   
    
    // $item = Item::findOrFail($id);
    $item   = DB::table('items')
                ->join('kategoris', 'items.kategori_id', '=', 'kategoris.id')
                ->where('items.id', '=', $id)
                ->select('items.*', 'kategoris.*', 'items.id', 'items.kategori_id')
                ->get();

    // dd($item);

    return view('master-dev/item/edit', compact('item'));

  }
```

**My View:**

```
<div class="card card-default">
            {{ Form::model($item,['route'=>['item.update',$item['id']], 'files'=>true,'method'=>'PUT']) }}
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title"><b>Edit Data Item</b></h3>
            <div class="card-tools">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <div class="card-body">
            @if(!empty($errors->all()))
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ Html::ul($errors->all())}}
          </div>
            @endif
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('kode_kategori', 'Kode Kategori') }}
              <select name="kode_kategori" id="kode_kategori" class="form-control">
              @foreach ($item as $i)
              <option valu="{{ $i['kode_kategori'] }}">{{ $i['kode_kategori'] }}</option>
              @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
               ..........
               ..........
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

I've tried any solutions in stackoverflow such as adding (ifempty...) and other solution but still the result `Undefined index: id` in my edit blade. When I was trying using `dd` and `vardump` the results was shown. I need to loop the `foreach` in my dropdown menu to show the list of data from my categories table. And I need to join my items table and my categories table to get the name of the categories.

Comment: you need to give alias to kategoris.id something like kategory_id

Answer (score 0):

you are calling same id from items and kategoris try this
public function edit($id)
{

```
    // $item = Item::findOrFail($id);
    $item   = DB::table('items')
                ->join('kategoris', 'items.kategori_id', '=', 'kategoris.id')
                ->where('items.id', '=', $id)
                ->select('items.*', 'kategoris.id as kategory_id', 'kategoris.kode_kategori', 'kategoris.kategori_name')
                ->get();

    // dd($item);

    return view('master-dev/item/edit', compact('item'));

  }
```

if this answer doesnot work show your database relation i will give you solution

Comment: Still got `Undefined index: id` I've already edit my post and add my tables relation. But when I use the `$item= Item::findorFail($id);` there's no problem, but I have to join the kategoris table with items table.

Comment: what returned $item= Item::findorFail($id);

Comment: look like issue in $item['id'] parameter in your form. $item['id']  and  @foreach ($item as $i) there is a conflict. pass hard coded value instead of $item['id'] and try, then you can debug it.

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe i am also think about it erorr should be there

Comment: Yes, it's right the problem is on the `form::model($item,[$item['id']....` it's conflicted with the `kategori_id`. I need to fix the controller, let me tried using alias first.

Answer (score 0):

`$item = ....->get()` will return a **Collection** to only have one item you need to use `$item = ....->first()` instead

But since you have `@foreach ($item as $i)` I believe, you still want to have a collection, but in that case, your issue is here

```
{{ Form::model($item,['route'=>['item.update',$item['id']], 'files'=>true,'method'=>'PUT']) }}
```

Since you have a collection, we don't know what `$item['id']` it's referring to. Perhaps `$item->first()['id']` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, there's a conflict fetching data from items and kategoris tables. There are differences calling a value with array and object, mostly if its data looped. So in the controller I must declared one by one, the selected value id from kategoris table, and I have to join both tables to get the name of the kategoris, and then I have to declare once more to get the list of the kategoris data. So there are three (3) variables to declare each one of them. For this long time I was looking for the short code in my Controller but I cannot find it.

Thank you for all of you guys helping me this problem. Cheers.